# How charge redistribution takes place in this switched capacitor DAC?

Tags: dac, switched-capacitor

[image]

So, I've trying to understand how this DAC works and until the moment it states that the Vref is connected to S1. At this moment, it says a voltage \$ \dfrac{V_{ref}}{2} \$ is added to \$ -A_{in} \$, although it doesn't matter the voltage at the capacitor in any exact moment, \$ V_{ref} \$ would force the voltage at point A to be only \$ \dfrac{V_{ref}}{2} \$ without this previous addition since it's a voltage source applied into 2 capacitors of value C in series.

So the question is:  Why is there a -Ain summed onto the value \$ \dfrac{V_{ref}}{2} \$?

Comment: This looks like an ADC, not a DAC

Comment: @user253751 It is part of a SAR ADC architecture yet it is a DAC. It can even be read in the first line of the figure.

Answer (score 1):

A was at 0V (connected to ground through Sc) before sampling began, and the bottom sides of all of the capacitors were at Ain. If the bottom sides of all of the capacitors are brought down to 0V by closing S1-S4, but the voltage across them stays the same (there's no circuit to discharge them), A must come down by the same amount, to -Ain.

Comment: The point it changes to -Ain I can see, it's only a change of reference. Yet that does not explain the fact Vref is applied to the circuit which normally would neglect any previous initial charge in the capacitor and the final value would be Vref across both capacitors and Vref/2 at point A.